# POST don't find

Tags: sqlite, post, try-catch

I have a problem with my code. When a I do a post don't find the autor and create a new register in table, but after with the first "try" find 2 with the same autor and launch a error.

Why don't find the try inside the reques.method ='POST'?. I know entry inside the if because in console print the except condition: "Usuario no exite".

Best Regards.

```
def usuario(request):
    user_actual=request.user.id
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_actual)
    new_form_data = {}
    miUsuario = FormularioUsuario(new_form_data)
    usuario = {}
    print(user)
    print(user_actual)
    print(Usuario.objects.get(autor= user_actual))
    try:
        usuario = Usuario.objects.get(autor= user_actual)
        new_form_data = {}
        new_form_data['irpf'] = usuario.irpf
        new_form_data['reduccion'] = usuario.reduccion
        new_form_data['guardar_normal'] = usuario.guardar_normal
        new_form_data['guardar_ertain'] = usuario.guardar_ertain
        new_form_data['guardar_berezi'] = usuario.guardar_berezi
        miUsuario = FormularioUsuario(new_form_data)
    except:
        print("No existe datos usuario")
    
        new_form_data = {}
        new_form_data['irpf'] = 0.0
        new_form_data['reduccion'] = 0.0
        new_form_data['guardar_normal'] = False
        new_form_data['guardar_ertain'] = False
        new_form_data['guardar_berezi'] = False
        miUsuario = FormularioUsuario(new_form_data)

    if request.method=='POST': #and ('guardar' in request.POST):
        miUsuario=FormularioUsuario(request.POST)
        print(user_actual)
        try:
            usuario = Usuario.objects.get(autor= user_actual)
            usuario.irpf = miUsuario.data['irpf']
            usuario.reduccion = miUsuario.data['reduccion']
            usuario.guardar_normal = miUsuario.data['guardar_normal']
            usuario.guardar_ertain = miUsuario.data['guardar_ertain']
            usuario.guardar_berezi = miUsuario.data['guardar_berezi']
            usuario.save()
            print("Guardado datos usuario")
        except:
            print("Usuario no existe")
            usuario = Usuario(autor= user,
                                    irpf= miUsuario.data['irpf'],
                                    reduccion = miUsuario.data['reduccion'],
                                    guardar_normal='guardar_normal' in miUsuario.data,
                                    guardar_ertain='guardar_ertain' in miUsuario.data,
                                    guardar_berezi='guardar_berezi' in miUsuario.data,) 
            usuario.save()                      

        new_form_data = {}
        new_form_data['irpf'] = usuario.irpf
        new_form_data['reduccion'] = usuario.reduccion
        new_form_data['guardar_normal'] = usuario.guardar_normal
        new_form_data['guardar_ertain'] = usuario.guardar_ertain
        new_form_data['guardar_berezi'] = usuario.guardar_berezi
        miUsuario = FormularioUsuario(new_form_data)

    return render(request, "BieleGastosApp/usuario_datos.html", {'usuario': miUsuario})
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

A good first step would be to find out which line in the try block is giving error. Use `except Exception as e:` and add `print(e)` to the except block. That should direct your attention to the specific error that is generated and help you make progress.